# Edit Mode pulls all records from default SelectMethod on ObjectDataSource after filtering records on alternate SelectMethod

Tags: gridview, objectdatasource

I know that someone is going to want code for this issue but the plumbing code for a Gridview, the Object Data Source and all its associated events, along with the wired up business objects is too much no matter how I could condense it.  However I think the question can still be answered.

I have an ObjectDataSource associated with a ASP.NET Gridview and a default SelectMethod named **GetALLNames**. This method say brings back 100 records by default and binds them to the GridView.

However on this page I have a 'Search' button (outside the grid) where the user can pick a single name and press 'Search'. The Search button changes the .SelectMethod to **GetNameByID**, returns the list, and binds the short filtered list to the Gridview. This works great too, as the GridView only has 1 record in it.

Now the issue, when I press the **Edit** button on this GridView to go into edit mode on the single record showing, the Object Data Source appears to be refetching ALL records from the default **GetALLNames** method via the cache (I have `EnableCaching="True"` on the ODS) . The result? The GridView *does indeed* go into edit mode, but for the 1st record out of the 100 original, and *not* into edit mode on the single filtered record.

Is there a way to prevent the ODS from refetching from that default list from the Cache *or* from calling the original **GetALLNames** method, and instead just go into Edit mode on the single record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar problem had me stumped for a while.  What finally clicked the light on for me was this statement:

> The ObjectDataSource control creates and destroys an instance of the
>   class for each method call; it does not hold the object in memory for
>   the lifetime of the Web request.

In my case, the ODS object was relying on a property being set before the select method was called (i.e. `ODS.partNumber="123"` followed by `ODS.getPart`).

To get the ODS to function correctly, I had to populate the object's required properties in the associated GridView's _RowEditing, _RowUpdating, and _RowCancellingEdit handlers.  That way, when the ODS object was *rebuilt* upon clicking any of those buttons in the GridView, all of the required properties were set.

It might not apply *exactly* in the same way in your case, but it could be related.